# How to delay a each job which gets pushed into a single queue

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.6, jobs

List of job's get dispatch in a queue, so for good. But now each job should be delayed with different timezones. Is this possible ?

```
dispatch(new ToClients($inputs))
  ->onQueue('notifications');
  // Need to add the timezone here
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use the scheduler for things like these? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: have you tried something like that `dispatch(new ToClients($inputs))
  ->onQueue('notifications')->delay(Carbon::now('Your/timzeone'));` ?

Comment: @JulienMetral Thats my plan exactly. Will it work or not is my doubt here.